# Compare two ETL trace file in Windows

Tags: xperf

I have an application with custom ETW logging. I use XPERF to listen to these channels and open the ETL trace for analysis.

Are there any tools out there which will help me compare 2 ETL files directly? I want to be able to measure the impact of a fix I am making.

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know such a tool. But you can dump the data in a txt file and compare the data there.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete. The 8.1 version of WPA supersedes it.

Answer (score 0):

The 8.1 version of WPA lets you compare two ETL files. You can see more details about the new features here:

http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/new-version-of-xperfupgrade-now/

I haven't used it a lot but in my brief experimentations it does seem to work.

The Microsoft documentation on comparing traces is well written and you should definitely read it as some aspects of trace comparison are not obvious.